# Using a CTE in Visual Studio 3 Queries

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, common-table-expression, tableadapter, subquery-factoring

I'm trying to get results from a subquery created as a SQL statement in a tableadapter in Visual Studio. The project is linked to an oracle database. I was originally trying to use a "with" clause, which works fine in Oracle, but not so much as a SQL query in Visual Studio. When I used the "with" clause, the error said "unable to parse query". Without the "with" clause I got the first two queries (Query 1 and Query 2) to work fine together in the tableadapter, but when I add the Main Query, I get an error 'SELECT' not recognized. FYI: I also tried using a stored procedure that the dataset would connect to but would not work on the Visual Studio side, so for now, I'm hoping to accomplish this with a SQL statement, rather than the stored procedure. Any help is appreciated.

```
    --- Query 1 ---

 SELECT * from (select
  ss.startdate
 ,ss.enddate
 ,s.segid
 ,s.segno
 ,s.stats
 ,sp.spo
 ,p.pro
FROM
 Spon ss
,Segs s
,pro p
,spo sp
WHERE
 and     ss.segid    =       s.segid
 and     ss.spoid    =       sp.spoid
 and     p.proid    =       sp.proid            
 and     ss.startdate    <=      (par_date1)
 and     ss.enddate      >=      (par_date2)
) sss,

    --- Query 2 ---

 (
SELECT
  p.pickid
  ,p.segid
  ,p.spid
  ,p.pickdate
  ,p.pickqty
FROM      picks p
WHERE
        (P.Pickdate is null or P.Pickdate between  (par_date1) and  ((par_date2))  )
) ppp

    --- Query 3 (MAIN Query - Queries data pulled from Query 1 and Query 2) ---

 SELECT
  sss.shipid
 ,sss.segno
 ,To_Char(sss.StartDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')  As StartDate
 ,To_Char(sss.EndDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')  As EndDate
 ,sss.Spo
 ,sss.Pro
 ,To_Char(ppp.PickDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') As PickDate
 ,To_Char(Max(ppp.PickDate), 'DD-MON-YYYY')   As LastPick
 ,Round(SUM(ppp.PickQty/(Count(distinct sss.spid)) ,2 )  As Avrg
 ,Count(sss.spid)  As TtlPicks
 ,sum(ppp.PickQty) As Ttls
    FROM sss, ppp
   WHERE
        ppp.spid(+)     =       sss.spid
   GROUP BY
 sss.shipid
,sss.segno
,sss.Spo
,sss.Pro
,To_Char(sss.StartDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
,To_Char(sss.EndDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
,To_Char(ppp.PickDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the FROM clause in the main (outer) query: `FROM sss, ppp`
Replace it with

```
FROM ( placeholder_1 ) sss, 
     ( placeholder_2 ) ppp
```

where `placeholder_1` should be replaced with the full text of Query #1 and `placeholder_2` with the full text of Query #2.

You may want to consider using ANSI standard syntax for the outer query... and in GROUP BY you will save time if you group by `trunc(sss.startdate)` and similar for the other dates; the effect is the same.

Good luck!

Comment: @Raspberry - I am not sure what you mean. What you already have is three distinct queries. What I show is one single query. What I suggested is: Take Query 3. Find its `FROM` clause, where it says `FROM sss, ppp`.  Now copy the full text of your query 1, paste it between `FROM` and `sss`, and put it in parentheses. This way it becomes a subquery or "inline view" instead of a CTE (in a `WITH` clause). Do the same thing with the full text of query 2: copy it, paste it between `sss,` and `ppp`, and enclose it in parentheses.

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry for the misunderstanding @mathguy. Thanks for your input! I will give it a try. :-).